# Google meet URL validity

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-hangouts

I created a meeting on google meet and shared the same with the team. I see,  I can use the same URL for any meetings in future. Is there any validity for URL? or it can be used only specific no of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [pricing documentation](https://apps.google.com/meet/pricing/):

- The maximum meeting length and number of participants is limited (depending on your plan).
- The number of meetings is for all GSuite plans (including the free one) unlimited.
- Browse through the linked documentation for further details, but in principle there is nothing preventing you from using the same URL in the future